# Can you transferee a message from a topic to an other after it exceeds a defined timeout in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there such a configuration in Kafka where it allows you to transferee a message that had exceeded its timeout from a topic to an other?.

For example if an order remains in "pending" topic for more than 5 mins, I want it to be moved to "failed" topic.

If not, what are the recommended practices to handle such a scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Records (actually, the whole segment file on disk) are permanently lost when they reach their retention timeout period.